# Plumber + leaflet don't render in angular

Tags: angular, shiny, leaflet, htmlwidgets, plumber

I am finding a lot issue to render a leaflet htmlwidget generated by a plumber endpoint in angular.

The angular app is quite simple, cause is making the post request and response will be render.

This is my code in R which is a very simple endpoint

```
library(plumber)
library(leaflet)
#* @tag leafletmap
#* @post /leafletmap
#* @serializer htmlwidget
function(res, req) {
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles()
}
```

But angular display a completly blank results.

[image]

In the console i have the following element

[image]

and in the network i can see that the html have been received.

[image]

what can i do to solve this?

I will report also the code for angular, in order to have a better understanding of this strange issue.

```
# xhr.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class XhrService {
  getGeoJSON(username: string, password: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      
      const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/AFS/leafletmap';
      
      xhr.open('POST', url, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            resolve(xhr.responseText);
          } else {
            reject(xhr.statusText);
          }
        }
      };

      // Invia il GeoJSON nel corpo della richiesta
      const geoJSON = '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"_leaflet_id":433,"feature_type":"polygon"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[13.3888,43.6117],[13.3892,43.6104],[13.3913,43.6106],[13.3919,43.6108],[13.393,43.6108],[13.394,43.6108],[13.3952,43.611],[13.3961,43.6111],[13.3965,43.6116],[13.397,43.612],[13.3963,43.6122],[13.3955,43.6124],[13.3951,43.6123],[13.3949,43.6127],[13.3946,43.6127],[13.3946,43.6123],[13.3942,43.6121],[13.394,43.6121],[13.3936,43.6122],[13.393,43.6121],[13.3927,43.6123],[13.3923,43.6124],[13.3912,43.6121],[13.3888,43.6117]]]}}]}';
      xhr.send(geoJSON);
    });
  }
}

# geojson-viewer-components.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { XhrService } from '../xhr.service';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-geojson-viewer',
  templateUrl: './geojson-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./geojson-viewer.component.css']
})
export class GeoJSONViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  geoJSONData: string = ''; // Initialize with an empty string
  formattedHtml: SafeHtml = ''; // Initialize with SafeHtml

  constructor(
    private xhrService: XhrService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const username = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
    const password = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';

    this.xhrService.getGeoJSON(username, password)
      .then(data => {
        this.geoJSONData = data;
        //this.geoJSONData = data;
        //console.log(data)

        this.formattedHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("geoJSONData");
      
        //this.formattedHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<pre>${this.geoJSONData}</pre>`);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Errore durante la richiesta:', error);
      });
  }
}

# geojson-viewer.components.ts
<div [innerHTML]="geoJSONData"></div>
```

If need it, i can share the html widget content with you

Comment: here you find the solution https://community.rstudio.com/t/plumber-leaflet-dont-render-in-angular/172463